# How to reference a variable value from the name in a variable?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have Googled and searched Stackoverflow with no success. Perhaps I do not know the correct words to use in order to find what I am seeking.

A simplistic view of the effort would be to check for the existence and correctness of project configuration variables. If these are not defined, then it is not setup correctly. Likewise, if the directory does not exist, then the project is not setup correctly.

**=== project_setup.bat**

```
@ECHO OFF
SET SOURCE_DIR=C:\src\project1
SET OBJECT_DIR=D:\intermediate\objects
SET TEST_DIR=C:\testing\project1
set SHIP_DIR=C:\final\project1
```

**=== check_project_directories.bat**

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET EXITCODE=0

SET DIR_LIST=^
SOURCE_DIR ^
OBJECT_DIR ^
TEST_DIR ^
SHIP_DIR

FOR %%v IN (%DIR_LIST%) DO (
    IF NOT DEFINED %%v (
        ECHO %%v is not defined.
        SET EXITCODE=1
    ) ELSE (
        REM === How to use the value of the variable rather than the variable name?
        IF NOT EXIST "%%v" (
            ECHO Directory for %%v does not exist.
            SET EXITCODE=1
        )
    )
)

EXIT /B %EXITCODE%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is the tidbit you need (in your `ELSE` statement):

```
SET VariableName=%%v
CALL SET VariableValue=%%!VariableName!%%
IF NOT EXIST "!VariableValue!" (
...
```

Or more succinctly (but less readable):

```
CALL SET VariableValue=%%%%v%%
IF NOT EXIST "!VariableValue!" (
...
```

Either will require you to change your `SETLOCAL` command to:

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
```

Essentially by adding the `CALL` in front of the `SET` statement you are telling the script to parse the respective line again but perform substitutions first.

This essentially makes the `CALL SET VariableValue=%%!VariableName!%%` evaluate to:

```
SET VariableValue=%SOURCE_DIR%
SET VariableValue=%OBJECT_DIR%
...
```

As it goes through the loop iterations which will set the `VariableValue` to the respective variable value you previously defined in your configuration.

Comment: Many thanks. If you know of any good references to this kind of material, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: There is not need for the VariableName variable. All you need is `if not exist "!%%v!"`

Comment: @dbenham - Wow, that does work. This is brilliantly simple and works perfectly when expansion is considered. Thanks for [another] good tip.